# QGIS Python AttributeError object has no attribute 'pushVersionInfo'

Tags: qgis, python, error, algorithm, attributeerror

I am unable to use almost all of the processing toolbox features in QGIS. I keep getting the following Python error across multiple algorithms:

> AlgorithmDialog.py", line 208, in runAlgorithm
>   self.feedback.pushVersionInfo() AttributeError:
>   'QgsProcessingFeedback' object has no attribute 'pushVersionInfo'

I'm new to QGIS and I am running 3.6.1-Noosa, although I have uninstalled it and updated to 3.6.2 twice. I'm not sure what that is about either.

QGIS code revision 2468226bc9.

Comment: Report a [bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues).  Shouldn't be a problem with the 3.4 LTS version as that code is new to 3.6.

Comment: It's not clear which version of QGIS you are using, is it 3.6.2 or are you back on 3.6.1?